# Is there a way to zip a from from within a SAS script without enabling XCMD?

Tags: sas

I have a user of a SAS server that wants to be able to "zip" a file they are outputting from a SAS script, by programming the file "zip" into the same script.

I'm hesitant to enable XCMD to allow this to be done natively on the Linux server on which SAS runs.  Does anyone know of an alternative way of doing this without enabling XCMD?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what they're doing.

If they're producing a .sas7bdat (SAS Dataset), then `options compress=yes;` (or `=char`) will compress the SAS dataset, some.  It won't compress nearly as much as normal gzip compression.

If they're writing out a text file, there is a method of writing a zip file.  In 9.4, this is production; see [this doc page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/65040/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1dn0f61yfyzton1l2ngsa1clllr.htm) for more information.  Basically you can write it like this:

```
filename myfile zip '//mydir/myfile.z';
```

and then write to it like a normal file.  You likely could write other kinds of files out to this as well (HTML, for example), if you read them in as text files and write them back out line by line to a zip fileref; but there's not much information available on this at the moment as it is brand new.

Prior to 9.4, there was the `SASZIPAM` filename engine, which is officially unsupported and not suitable for production use.  You may be able to use it similarly.

If they're writing a PDF or similar file, then probably there is no suitable method for doing so, unless you can use the zip filename engine by reading the pdf in with recfmt=n and writing back out to the zip that way; that seems very dangerous, though.

The best solution from my point of view if you aren't comfortable enabling XCMD would be to have SAS write out a batch file (so a .sh file in Linux I suppose) containing the zip instructions, and have the process that runs SAS execute that .sh file when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If your output goes to an ODS destination you can create an ODS package and include all output in zip file.

```
ods package open;
ods html package;
 proc print data=sashelp.class;
 run;
ods html close;
ods package publish archive properties(archive_name="class.zip" archive_path="\");
ods package close;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a UNIX install so I cannot test this with -NOXCMD.

In Unix, you can use SAS to write through a [pipe](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/63053/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1ceb0xedanuj3n19l3g73awk1wf.htm) like you would any other Unix process.