# Reading zipped sas datasets and zipping them on the fly

Tags: unix, sas, gzip

I am working with large files on a unix server with gzip compression capabilities and for space purposes would like for files to remain zipped. I know how to read in a zipped txtfile, but would then like to:
1) zip the dataset created from the zipped txtfile
2) Later set this zipped sas dataset in another datastep/procedure.

Is this possible? If so please alter the code below, this is what I would like to do:

```
libname lib "path";
filename txtfile PIPE "gzip -dc filepath";

data lib.ds1; **would like this to be a zipped sas dataset**;
    infile txtfile dlm="|" missover dsd;
    input *columns*;
run;
data lib.ds2; **would like this to be a zipped sas dataset**;
    set lib.ds1; *setting the zipped sas dataset;
run;
```

Comment: See also the related [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457033/is-there-a-way-to-zip-a-from-from-within-a-sas-script-without-enabling-xcmd); some of those concepts might also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing GZIP command from the SAS session.

```
data _null_;
  command = 'gzip -c /path/ds2.sas7bdat > /path/ds2.sas7bdat.gz';
  call system (command);
run;
```

For testing purposes, keep -c option.  That way you can keep the original file and compare it with the newly compressed one.

Comment: Note that this requires `OPTIONS XCMD` which is off by default in server instances of SAS.

Answer (score 2):

SAS cannot store sas dataset in zipped format( *.7z / *.gzip / *.zip etc) using simple datastep like you want. You would need external zip utility to do so(using x statement etc) or using ods package. Separate logic would need to be separately coded for decompressing and compressing zip file before reading and after reading of SAS dataset respectively.

Though SAS has inbuilt ability to compress the dataset that are created using COMPRESS= data set option or system option to compress a data file. The compression is pretty good.

```
OPTIONS COMPRESS=(YES|CHAR|BINARY)
```

or

```
DATA MYSASDATA(COMPRESS=YES|CHAR|BINARY);
```

You can read more in the language reference on the algorithm SAS uses to compress the dataset.

Refer the following link from SAS Language Ref for more detail : http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202890.htm

Comment: The compression is okay, but it's not nearly as good as Zip compression or similar.  I remember one project where I had datasets uncompressed 10GB, compressed 2GB, zipped 10mb.  (Lots of sparse data.)